# How to set a usb camera as a source to wpf MediaElemt in VS2010 in c#?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, usb, camera, mediaelement

I have a Windows WPF application and I want to stream a video from my usb camera using MediaElement control. Is it possible to set usb camera as source to MediaElement?
I'm using VS2010 framework 4.0 and c# language.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/